# Difficulty with Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to create a simple program that takes in specifically two specifically placed destinations and shows the directions in between them. For whatever reason, I just cannot get the directions to show up.

```
<script>
  var directionsService = new google.maps.directionsService();
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.directionsRenderer();

  var new_york = {lat: 40.7128, lng: -74.0060};
  var los_angeles = {lat: 34.0522, lng: -118.2437};

  function initMap() {
    var mapMarkers = [];
    var map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 4, center: {lat: 40, lng: -99}}
    );
    var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new_york, 
      map: map, 
      title: 'Home'
    });
    var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: los_angeles, 
      map: map, 
      title: 'School'
    });
  }
  calculateAndDisplayRoute: function(directionsService, directionsDisplay, new_york, los_angeles) {
  directionsService.route({
    origin: new_york,
    destination: los_angeles,
    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
    alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDmA98U4We-2IAaHbxa354v_C91IktiSKM3&callback=calculateAndDisplayRoute"></script>
```

Comment: Please upload your code

Comment: You have syntax errors in the posted code.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a few problems with your code, first you need to be aware that the google maps library needs to be loaded before you can create new instances of `DirectionsService` and `DirectionsRenderer`, which btw should be in CamelCase:

```
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
```

Since you are not loading the maps library asynchronously you can place the script at the top of your page and just drop the callback argument. I've made a few changes to your code, please check it out below (you need to add your api key):

```js
var new_york = {lat: 40.7128, lng: -74.0060};
var los_angeles = {lat: 34.0522, lng: -118.2437};

function initMap() {
  var mapMarkers = [];

  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 4, center: {lat: 40, lng: -99}}
  );

  var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new_york, 
    map: map, 
    title: 'Home'
  });

  var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: los_angeles, 
    map: map, 
    title: 'School'
  });
}
      
function calculateAndDisplayRoute() { 
  initMap();

  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

  var route = {
    origin: new_york,
    destination: los_angeles,
    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
  };

  directionsService.route(route, function(response, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}

calculateAndDisplayRoute();
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=???"></script>
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
```